# How to build an Android app on Raspberry pi?

Tags: android, software-development

As you may know, the Android development system is available for the Raspberry Pi from the Debian project here:
https://packages.debian.org/buster/android-sdk
However, they do not include Android Studio.
Is there a good tutorial on how to develop Android apps on the Pi without Android Studio?

Comment: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/develop-android-app-raspberry-pi

Comment: @JaromandaX The article describes making PWAs, not native Android apps, on the Pi.

Comment: oops, sorry - yeah, there's nothing out there - probably because compilation is apparently way too slow on a pi (based on a similar question in this forum)

Comment: No matter what, this is going to be an absolutely dreadful experience.  If there is  any other option at all, don't do this.  In fact, even if there isn't any other option, don't do this: Find something more realistic to do with your time, such as building a motorcyle blindfolded (yes, a joke, but I think these might be on par difficulty and enjoyability wise), until you have a proper laptop or something to run AS on.

Comment: @goldiocks I don't think you've used a Raspberry pi 4. It is quite fast and 8GB is tons of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android programming is not possible natively on the Raspberry Pi, because the various Android packages do not include the SDK manager which is needed to download related software. The SDK manager is now a part of Android Studio which has not been ported to the Pi.

However there is one way to build Android apps on the Pi, by using Qemu to **emulate an x86_64 running any x86 Linux distro and then installing the x86 Android Studio in that.** It is *very* slow but it seems to work. This is a case where it might be wise to overclock the Pi, and you should run Qemu with the -smp option to specify multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command for install android studio on Raspberry Pi but
it is not native!.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libstdc++6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
```

You must install snap and then:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

android studio installed on raspberry pi.

Other way you can use windows 11 arm.

Windows 11 ARM on Raspberry Pi can run android studio windows and worked!